How to show $x'''(y)=\frac{3y''(x)^2}{y'(x)^5}-\frac{y'''(x)}{y'(x)^4}$?
The question states that you have to show:
$$\frac{d^3x}{dy^3}=\frac{3}{(\frac{dy}{dx})^5} (\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})^2 - \frac{1}{(\frac{dy}{dx})^4} \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$$
I have tried so far to rewrite them in terms of the derivative definition but that leads nowhere. The question is from Martin and Shaw, Mathematics for Physicists.
Thank you.
EDIT:
as per previous guides from users on the forum, i have been instructed to show my process and more specifically where I got stuck.
I simplified this question thinking from the start that something would eventually cancel when substituting the limit definitions.
First I rewrote as:
$$\frac{3(f''(x))^2-f'(x)f'''(x)}{(f'(x))^5}.$$
Then, from knowing that
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\delta(x)\to\ 0}\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}$$
I found that
$$f''(x)=\lim_{\delta(x)\to\ 0}\frac{f(x+2\delta x)-2f(x+\delta x)+f(x)}{(\delta x)^2}$$
And then
$$f'''(x)=\lim_{\delta(x)\to\ 0}\frac{f(x+3\delta x)-f(x+2\delta x)+3f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{(\delta x)^3}$$
After I substituted I got this expression and I'm stuck at this stage:
$$\lim_{\delta(x)\to\ 0}\frac{\frac{3(f(x+2\delta x))^2+9(f(x+\delta x))^2+(f(x))^2+3f(x)f(x+2\delta x)-9f(x+2\delta x)f(x+\delta x) -8f(x+\delta x)f(x)-f(x+3\delta x)f(x+\delta x)+f(x+3\delta x )f(x)}{(\delta x)^4}}{(\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x})^5}$$
I don't think this is the correct way, even though I presume that there must be some grouping and then L'Hospital to apply. I also do not know other properties for nth derivative in Leibniz notation which could maybe make this easier.
Sorry for the long post

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Your equation is certainly not true for every function $y(x)$, so there must be something important you're leaving out.

The result follows quite easily just using implicit differentiation/chain rule and product rule. Have you tried that?

Starting with $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, differentiating both sides w.r.t. $y$ by the chain rule yields
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} &= \frac d{dy} \left[\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}\right] \\
&= \frac d{dx} \left[\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}}\right] \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} \\
&= \frac{-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \cdot\frac1{\frac{dy}{dx}} \\
&= -\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3}
\end{align*}$$
Try using the same process to determine the third derivative.

Thank you very much!

Here are a couple of steps to make the equation look quite different without solving it completely. Since $y$ does not appear outside of a derivative, we can make the substitution $u = \smash{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}$, so the equation becomes
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} 
= \frac{3}{u^5} \Bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} \Bigr)^2
- \frac{1}{u^4} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x^2}.
$$
Now multiply through by denominator $u^5$ and collect like terms to get
$$
(u^5 + u) \frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} 
= 3 \Bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} \Bigr)^2 
$$
or
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}x^2} 
= \frac{3}{u^5 + u} \Bigl( \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} \Bigr)^2, 
$$
which is non-linear, but at least it's only second order.
If we can solve this equation for $u$, then we can recover $y$ as an antiderivative of $u$.
